# Android: How to handle a lot of UI elements change depending on SharedPreferences values

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sharedpreferences

**Introduction:**
I have created custom settings for my application and all of setting's data is depending on SharedPreferences.
Basically I have some switches (7 to be exact) and spinners, and textviews and on activity launch I get value from SharedPreferences which can be booleans, int or strings.
I have created complex logics and I don't want to switch to Preference activity.

**Previously:**
I had an activity with viewpager and TabLayout and activity was launching with a long delay.

Basically what used to happen was: user clicked on button to launch settings and he had to wait for minimum 3 seconds (sometime even 5 seconds) with MainActivity freezed and then Settings would launch.

**Currently:**
So I transformed fragments to activities and tried to use NavigationDrawer to switch between 3 activities instead of 3 tabs.

I created a base activity with NavigationDrawer and extended it from other 3 activities so all of them would use same NavigationDrawer.

Basically now on button click I'm launching first Activity and it gets launched immediately but still there's a delay of 2 seconds and it keeps showing white screen and then would load content with switches, textviews and spinner values set.

I tried with Fragments but they lag when replacing one with another and also loading time was same.

**How settings works:**
One spinner is depending on other spinner's state (enabled/disabled, on/off). When activity is created I have to get values from SharedPreferences like for instance a boolean with value true and turn on first switch which will enable all other switches and should update some shared preference values.
All this happens in activity's onCreate so delay is justified obviously.

**My questions:**

Am I doing it right or should I use some background tasks?

How should I reduce the loading time (if possible)?

Is there another way to get these values elsewhere maybe and then when activity is launched I recall these values and content is shown immediately?

**Edit:** Unfortunately I don't have demonstrative code. I tried to explain all in my post to give more or less an idea of what I did.

Comment: Not much to do without the code. But getting and updating shared preferences should not take much time- try to locate  where the heavy lifting is and optimize. My guess is that its something with your views not the shared preferences

Comment: @X3Btel Now that you mentioned view I want to add another detail, I have added imageviews and they are a lot.. I use them as icons. Maybe that's causing this delay. I will try to see without them... Thanks for the input